# Как подсчитать сколько раз повторяется строка?

Tags: python, строки, подстрока

Пожалуйста подскажите, как подсчитать сколько раз входит строка в текст?
Нужно взять строку проверить совпадения в базе, вывести строку и число ее вхождений в документ.

Пример готового решения:

```
7   5   9   3   1 - 251 раз.
2   11  7   2   2 - 2354 раз.
```

Примеры строк:

```
7   5   9   3   1
17  2   11  1   0
2   11  7   2   2
18  3   6   2   1
8   5   10  4   2
12  8   9   4   1
14  11  6   2   2
13  5   2   1   0
14  5   3   2   2
16  11  8   4   0
17  6   13  1   2
3   8   13  3   0
11  6   7   3   2
4   11  9   4   0
4   4   12  4   2
```

Что было сделано?
Обновление. Сделал через `collections.Counter()`

```
c = collections.Counter()    
with open('alldata.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            search = str(row).replace("\t", "").replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", "")
            c[search] += 1
            x = f'{str(search)},{str(c[search])}'
            print(x)
```

Вывод `print()`

```
**11    5   13  3   2   2203**
8   8   5   4   2   2192
**11    5   13  3   2   2191**
8   8   5   4   2   2191
**11    5   13  3   2   2190**
8   8   5   4   2   2190
```

Подсчет идет с дубликатами, почему? Как исключить дубликаты?

Comment: Да можно просто в `collections.Counter` скормить строки и он их сам посчитает.

Answer (score 2):

```
st = 'Текст'
counter = st.count('Строка, которую ты ищешь')
```

Метод 'count' позволяет узнать количество вхождений элемента в контейнер, в твоём случае, количество вхождений строки в текст. Для того чтобы перебрать все строки, забей их в список и с помощью цикла for перебери все строки методом 'count', а дальше всё зависит от того, для чего ты эту информацию будешь использовать. Но, думаю, что с форматированием данных ты справишься.